# Accessing the Name attribute of an object

Tags: c#, schema

I have this code. I want to access the "Name" attribute of the object because type contains something like

> {Name="String", FullName="System.String"}

but i want only "string".

```
DataTable dt = dr.GetSchemaTable();
foreach (DataRow myField in dt.Rows){
   var name = myField["ColumnName"];
   var type = myField["DataType"];
   Console.Out.WriteLine("type = " + type.toString());
}
```

ideas ?

Comment: what type is it? What does the type.GetType() say

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could cast to the corresponding type and then access the Name property:

```
var type = (Type)myField["DataType"];
Console.WriteLine("type = " + type.Name);
```

Comment: you solved my problem. thanks. i am a noob, so please be patient :-D

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `type.ToString()` but `((Type)type).Name`.